Power Automate: Issues with formulas after adding a row to a table
I have created a Microsoft Power Automate flow that creates a new row in an excel table every time a survey response is submitted in Survey 123. On a separate excel sheet, I have coded "IF" statements to correspond a value to the submitted survey response. For example, if predator activity was reported as "present" in the survey, the corresponding value in Sheet 2 would be "0". I did that using this code: =IF(Sheet1!A2="Present", 0, IF(Sheet1!A2="Absent", 27, 0))
I am having an issue when a new response is submitted. The formula entered into a cell will skip the new row and will not be applied to Sheet 2. For example, the formula is written to code for "Sheet1!A12" but once a new response is submitted, it will change to code for "Sheet1!A13". Therefore, the numbers are not automatically updating with the flow. The only way to change this is to re-drag the formula through the column.
Does anyone know a way to prevent the change in formula from happening?
I have tried transferring the values to a different sheet and recoding the cells, but neither of these have worked.

Show us screenshots, sorry but I'm not following.

If you haven't already, could you try entering this dynamic one in the first cell with IF(Sheet1!A2="Present"... in Sheet2 (and delete the ones below):
=SWITCH(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$500,"Present",0,"Absent",27,"")

adjusting the range and default value("") to suit your purpose.

This worked! Thank you

Glad to hear it!

why don't you use a Sharepoint list instead of Excel spreadsheet? Any time you need the physical xlsx file, you can export it with two clicks
